# React-Native firebase signup and login

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm creating an app for Android on react native and i have created a signup page and trying to create the user on firebase so then one can create an account and use also firebase to login. My signup page is the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { Button, TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import app from './firebaseConfig';

const SignUpScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');

  const signUp = async () => {
    const auth = getAuth(app);
    try {
      const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      // Signed in 
      const user = userCredential.user;
      // ...
      Alert.alert('Success', 'Account created successfully');
      navigation.navigate('Login');
    } catch (error) {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      // ..
      Alert.alert('Error', errorMessage);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        label="Email"
        value={email}
        onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)}
      />
      <TextInput
        label="Password"
        value={password}
        onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}
        secureTextEntry
      />
      <Button mode="contained" onPress={signUp}>
        Sign Up
      </Button>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')}>
        Already have an account? Log in
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 16,
  },
});
```

And i have the firebaseConfig that is copy pasted from google:

```
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "MY_API_KEY",
  authDomain: "myapp.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "myapp",
  storageBucket: "myapp.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "SenderID",
  appId: "appID",
  measurementId: "GoogleAnalytics Tag"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

when i try to create an account im getting a console warning:

```
    Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 2):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProvider' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProvider' of undefined
    at _getProvider (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:165995:56)
    at getAuth (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:165726:36)
    at ?anon_0_ (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct:80/SignUpScreen.bundle?platform=android&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=true&dev=true&minify=false&runModule=true&shallow=true:29:38)
    at next (native)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:20720:26)
    at _next (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:20739:29)
    at anonymous (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:20744:14)
    at tryCallTwo (/root/react-native/ReactAndroid/hermes-engine/.cxx/Release/2q6r403w/arm64-v8a/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:61:9)
    at doResolve (/root/react-native/ReactAndroid/hermes-engine/.cxx/Release/2q6r403w/arm64-v8a/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:216:25)
    at Promise (/root/react-native/ReactAndroid/hermes-engine/.cxx/Release/2q6r403w/arm64-v8a/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:82:14)
    at anonymous (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:20736:25)
    at apply (native)
    at signUp (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct:80/SignUpScreen.bundle?platform=android&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=true&dev=true&minify=false&runModule=true&shallow=true:42:27)
    at _performTransitionSideEffects (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:55669:22)
    at _receiveSignal (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:55625:45)
    at onResponderRelease (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:55492:34)
    at apply (native)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackProd (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2554:21)
    at apply (native)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2640:42)
    at apply (native)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2643:36)
    at executeDispatch (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2707:48)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2724:26)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3830:35)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3837:43)
    at forEach (native)
    at forEachAccumulated (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3166:22)
    at runEventsInBatch (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3848:27)
    at runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3907:25)
    at anonymous (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3888:42)
    at batchedUpdates$1 (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:14128:20)
    at batchedUpdates (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3819:36)
    at _receiveRootNodeIDEvent (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3887:23)
    at receiveTouches (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3930:34)
    at apply (native)
    at __callFunction (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:19861:36)
    at anonymous (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:19630:31)
    at __guard (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:19820:15)
    at callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (http://jv5tlkm.prodester.8081.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.prodester.gratichain&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:19629:21)
```

and it doesnt seem to create any users. Not sure where can i go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are importing this

```
import app from './firebaseConfig';
```

but in `./firebaseConfig` you are not exporting

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

should be

```
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

then

```
import {app} from './firebaseConfig';
```